# How to set registry value with Get-Item().SetValue [UnauthorizedAccessException]

Tags: powershell

Use Get-Item then chain with GetValue works:

```bsh
(Get-Item -path "HKCU:\Environment" ).GetValue('Path', '', 'DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
```

Use Get-Item then chain with SetValue doesn't works:

```bsh
(Get-Item -path "HKCU:\Environment" ).SetValue('Path', 'test', 'ExpandString')
```

I got the following error:

```bsh
Exception lors de l'appel de « SetValue » avec « 3 » argument(s) : « Impossible d'écrire dans la clé de Registre. »
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 1
+ (Get-Item -path "HKCU:\Environment").SetValue('Path', '%test%', 'Expa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I have tried with Administrator Privilege (aka right-click Run As Administrator) and with -force flag, but no better result.

What am I doing wrong ?

Regards,

Comment: Set the value using `Set-ItemProperty` instead of set value like `Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Control Panel\Desktop' -Name MenuShowDelay -Value 50`

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is a month old, but try this

```
$Environment = (Get-Item -Path 'HKCU:').OpenSubKey('Environment', $true)
$Environment.SetValue('Path', 'Test', 'ExpandString')
```